# Play Framework 2 -- custom loggers in production?

Tags: scala, logging, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a class with a custom logger. Here's a trivial example:

```
package models

import play.Logger

object AModel {
  val log = Logger.of("amodel")

  def aMethod() {
    if (! log.isInfoEnabled) log.error("Can't log info...")
    log.info("Logging aMethod in AModel")
  }
}
```

and then we'll enable this logger in `application.conf`:

```
logger.amodel=DEBUG
```

and in development (Play console, use `run`) this logger does indeed log. But in production, once we hit the message

```
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
```

loggers defined like the above logger fail to log any further and instead we go through the error branch. It seems their log level has been changed to `ERROR`.

Is there anyway to correct this undesirable state of affairs? Is there special configuration for production logs?

**edit**

Play's handling of logs in production is a source of difficulty to more than a few people... https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1186

For some reason it ships its own `logger.xml` which overrides `application.conf`.

Comment: Have you tried creating your own logback logger xml file and specifying it from the production startup command with `-Dlogger.file=$CUSTOM_FILE`?  Then you should be able to include something like `<logger name="amodel" level="INFO,DEBUG" />`.

Comment: Putting together something for `conf/application-logger.xml` worked in the end. Since we're using `play dist` (really `play universal:package-zip-tarball`) I am not sure how to pass options like you are suggesting.

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24506476/2408961